# Selecting and re-selecting from a combo box

Tags: java, user-interface, combobox

Okay so for the end project of the semester of Java we're doing a battle simulation. One of my group partners convinced me that a GUI would be a great idea, and so far it's working out well except for one thing. I want the end user to be able to click on the combo box to select one thing, and allow it to show up in the label at the bottom of the window, and that part I'm good with. However, once the user selects from the combo box, I want them to be able to change their selection. I know there's the option to allow a multi-selection, but I'm looking more for a mutually exclusive thing than being able to select two. In no way is my code complete, but here's some of it:

```
public void setHair()
{
        //Hair Options for both size and color displayed in a window
    window.setSize(400,400);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(window.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setTitle("Hair Options");
    window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    buildHairColorPanel();
    window.add(colorPanel);
    window.add(scrollPane);
    buildLengthPanel();
    window.add(lengthPanel);
   }
```

And here's the build methods:

```
private void buildLengthPanel()
{
    lengthList = new JList(hairLengths);
    lengthList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    lengthList.addListSelectionListener(new ListListener());
    lengthList.setVisibleRowCount(6);
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(lengthList);
    lengthPanel.add(scrollPane);
    lengthPanel.add(colorList);

}

    private void buildHairColorPanel()
    {
        colorList = new JList(hairColors);
        colorList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        colorList.addListSelectionListener(new ListListener());
        colorList.setVisibleRowCount(6);
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(colorList);
        colorPanel.add(scrollPane);
        colorPanel.add(colorList);

    }
```

I know this is a syntax thing or that I need to change a setting but I can't find a reference on how to do it in my textbook, and can't seem to narrow my question down well enough to find a reference to it.

Incidentally, all 18 options are visible for the color stuff rather than the six that I was trying to set it to with the addition of a scrollpane (and the scrollpane doesn't show up either) although that's not my main issue, I'd appreciate the info it if it was something quick to point out to fix.

Ah, forgot that I had to write this to go with it too:

```
public class ListListener
implements ListSelectionListener
{
public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e)
{
String selection = (String) colorList.getSelectedValue();
selectedColor.setText(selection);
}
}
```

Comment: One thing I've noticed so far, under `lengthPanel.add(colorList);` you probably mean to add `lengthList` instead.

Comment: Oye. Now only one combobox shows up instead of both of them showing up when debugging.

Comment: *"One of my group partners convinced me that a GUI would be a great idea,.."*  Smack them upside the head.  1) It does not sound as though a GUI is part of the specification of the problem.  2) A GUI is harder to code than a command line app. Creating GUIs is an advanced topic.

Comment: I'd have to smack myself upside the head too, because I'm the one that told our professor I was bored with the usual stuff and he told me to give him a better one... so I did. Which is why we have a battle simulation instead of a dice simulation. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I myself would rather do a ComboBox like Andrew suggested, but if you would like to keep the same lists I've got a working prototype based off what you've provided here.

First, I didn't have much luck using two panels on the frame, so I combined the two into one panel.

```
buildHairColorPanel();
window.add(colorPanel);
window.add(scrollPane);
buildLengthPanel();
window.add(lengthPanel);
```

to

```
buildHairPanel();
window.add(hairPanel);
```

Next, each list needs its own `ListListener` and its own `JScrollPane`

```
colorScrollPane = new JScrollPane(colorList);
lengthScrollPane = new JScrollPane(lengthList);
colorList.addListSelectionListener(//Look Below...
lengthList.addListSelectionListener(//Look Below...
```

Lastly, you only want to add the ScrollPanes to the panel, not the List itself.

```
hairPanel.add(colorScrollPane);
```

<strike>`hairPanel.add(colorList);`</strike>

Altogther, you could copy-paste this into its own class and run it to test:
Note that I had to provide a lot of fields that are not initialized in your code, and since I simply use them from the main() method I labeled them as static, which is probably not necessary in your code.

```
    static JList lengthList;
    static JList colorList;
    static JScrollPane lengthScrollPane;
    static JScrollPane colorScrollPane;
    static JPanel hairPanel = new JPanel();
    static JLabel selectedColor = new JLabel();
    static JLabel selectedLength = new JLabel();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        //Hair Options for both size and color displayed in a window
        window.setSize(400,400);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(window.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setTitle("Hair Options");
        window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        window.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

        buildHairPanel();
        window.add(hairPanel);

        window.setVisible(true);
    }


    private static void buildHairPanel()
    {
        //Build Hair Color Selection
        String[] hairColors = new String[] { "brown", "blonde", "black", "red", "green", "blue" };
        colorList = new JList(hairColors);
        colorList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

        colorList.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e)
            {
                String selection = (String) optionsSelect.colorList.getSelectedValue();
                optionsSelect.selectedColor.setText(selection);
            }
        });

        colorList.setVisibleRowCount(3);
        colorScrollPane = new JScrollPane(colorList);
        hairPanel.add(colorScrollPane);

        //Build Hair Length Selection
        String[] hairLengths = new String[] { "short1", "short2", "medium1", "medium2", "long1", "long2" };
        lengthList = new JList(hairLengths);
        lengthList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

        lengthList.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener(){
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e)
            {
                String selection = (String) optionsSelect.lengthList.getSelectedValue();
                optionsSelect.selectedLength.setText(selection);
            }
        });

        lengthList.setVisibleRowCount(3);
        lengthScrollPane = new JScrollPane(lengthList);
        hairPanel.add(lengthScrollPane);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to accept your answer. It took me a bit to have a chance to come back to this with the end of the semester running up. Your information was great and it fixed all of my issues! Now to implement the other methods and variables with my new information!

Answer (score 1):

I would start by using a [JComboBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#eg) which, if you want only one item selected at a time, is the way to go. Then you can use `myComboBox.addItemListener(this)` to create a listener that waits for a selection inside the myComboBox object. The code would look something like this:

```
public void myClass implements ItemListener {

    String[] choices = {"Choice 1", "Choice 2", "Choice 3", "etc..."};

    public myClass() {
        JComboBox myComboBox = new JComboBox(choices);
        myComboBox.addItemListener(this);
        JLabel myLabel = new JLabel("Hello World");
        // You still will need to extend JFrame in this class if you so choose
        // The main purpose of showing a class is to show that you need to
        // Implement ItemListener
    }

    // Your other stuff here

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        if(e.getStateChanged() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            myLabel.setText(e.getItem().toString());
        }
    }
}
```